# No controller specified in route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, razor, html-helper

### Situation:

I have a ASP.NET application where I have different controllers. I changed in the **RouteConfig** the route to:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "SpecificRoute", 
    "{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

All pages in my the **HomeController** are working fine. One way I go to them is with a ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index Page", "Index", "Home")
```

And that works fine, even as other ways with the context as: "*example*", "Home".

It goes wrong when I select an other controller, let's say:

```
@Html.ActionLink("GoToErrorPage", "NotFound", "Error") // error page
```

The result of this link is that it just connects to the home page. It does not go the the correct page.

---

I want to connect to all pages (in other controller's too) with a URL like:

> http://localhost:12345/Request

How the original url looked like (before the change in the **RouteConfig**)

> http://localhost:12345/Home/Request

---

### Question:

1. How do I need to configure the **RouteConfig**?
2. How do I set it that I don't need to type the controller before the
       action in the url?
3. How do I set the ActionLink correct?

Comment: Both your routes are the same (they can accept 2 segments). If you want specific routes, they need to be distinguishable. But if you want to be able to omit the controller (or something that identifies the controller), then you need to create a route for every method in your application.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How do I make them distinguish from each other? Or how do I create a specific route for every page?

Comment: If you want to go to the `Request()` method of `HomeController` with just `../Request`, the you need a specific route with `url: Request/{id}` and `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Request", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` (placed before the default route)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Works! Answer this below, You have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your routes are effectively the same in that they both match any url with 2 segments. If you want to be able to navigate to a method without specifying the controller name, then you will need to create specific routes for each of those methods. For example if you want to navigate to the `Request(int? id)` method of `HomeController`, with `../Request` or `../Request/1` then you need

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Request", 
    "Request/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Request", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and that route must be placed before the default route

Then in the view `@Html.ActionLink("Request Page", "Request", "Home")` will generate a url of `../Request` and go the the `Request()` method of `HomeController`